# Чем хуже скорость SSD при подключении в SATA 2.0

Tags: железо, ssd, пк

У меня на материнской плате интерфейс подключения SATA 2.0 Хочу поставить SSD вместо HDD, из этого выплывает вопрос: так как современные SSD совместимы с интерфейсом SATA 3.0 (заведомо знаю что скорость передачи данных у SATA 2.0 = до 3 Gb/s а в SATA 3.0 до 6 Gb/s) поэтому интересно на сколько сильно я потеряю в скорости если буду использовать SSD подключенным по SATA 2.0 нежели чем по SATA 3.0 и будет ли это заметно в повседневной работе?

Comment: было дело, что в ноутбуке c sata 2.0 поменял винт на ssd... прирост может и был, но я его не заметил

Answer (score 1):

Заметно не будет, основной эффект от SSD скорость доступа к данным, а не просто скорость копирования, SATA 2.0 имеет скорость 300 Мбайт/с что конечно не даст в полной мере реализовать потенциал многих SSD дисков, но разница при замене HDD на SSD всёравно будет очень заметна.